Oculus ID return 0 and Username is empty
We require to get the Display name and Username for unique identification of our devices as they are logged in with specific Oculus account. I have setup an account on Oculus developer dashboard as required as well as doing all the certifications and requirements > data use checkup.
The code in the Game Manager class is as follows:
using UnityEngine;
using Oculus.Platform;
using Oculus.Platform.Models;

public bool InitOculus()
{
    try
    {
        Core.Initialize(123****132);
        Users.GetLoggedInUser().OnComplete(LoggedInUser);
    }
    catch (UnityException e)
    {
        Debug.LogException(e);
        UnityEngine.Application.Quit();
    }
    return true;
}

void LoggedInUser(Message msg)
{
    string name = "";
    string username = "";
    if (msg.IsError)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Failed to retrieve Oculus user.");
    }
    else
    {
        User user = msg.GetUser();
        ulong userId = user.ID;
        Debug.Log("USER ID IS " + userId);
        username = user.OculusID;
        Users.Get(userId).OnComplete(message =>
        {
            if (!message.IsError)
            {
               
                name = message.Data.DisplayName;
            }
            else
            {
                var e = message.GetError();
                Debug.LogError($"Error loading display name: {e.Message}.");
            }
        });
    }
    Debug.Log("Display Name " + name + " and the username is " + username);
}

I am posting here because there are some other posts (stackoverflow/Oculus) regarding this issue but they are either too old to be valid or unanswered. I have also tried the check entitlement and callback approach but that does not work either as our app is not published through Oculus store, we have in-house platform.
Thank you in advance.

I had a similar problem, but I was using a test user created by meta. The problem resolved itself after uploading a build to the ALPHA realese channel.

Unfortunately that will not work for our case because we have in-house publishing platform. So if I publish the app with an invited test user it will work for the production build but not for the deployment build, unless I missed something?

I think you need to upload at least a build to a realse channel in the dashboard so Meta registers your application. TBH I havent tested it as much as I wanted because I am having problems right now trying to share sapital anchors between 2 users and I am behind schedule :(

Okay I shall give a try thank you :)
